# Creating elements through a function, and appending the new elements to parents in the render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that I want to return data from through iteration, e.g.,
`{"hello": 1, "world": 2}`

Could I write a function that iterated through the object, and return the values as elements, like so:

```
iterateObject() {
    for (var key in myObject) {
        return <span>{myObject[key]}</span>
    }
}
```

And if I can return elements that way, how would I go about adding them to existing parent elements in my render function?

```
render() {
    return(
        <div className="objectData">
            APPEND NEW ELEMENTS HERE
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The issue you have with your `iterateObject` function is that you're returning the very first item, so the for loop doesn't even get to the second item, let alone the 3rd, 4th, 5th etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the Array from `map()`:

```
iterateObject() {
    return Object.values(myObject).map((item,i) => {
        return <span key={i}>{item}</span>
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="objectData">
            {this.iterateObject()}
        </div>
    )
}
```